# Foursquare Test Push receiving a 301 (Moved Permanently) response

Tags: real-time, foursquare

I'm updating my consumer to use the User Push API. I've enabled SSL in my domain and everything is detected fine.

However, using the "Send a push test" at consumer page I get *"Your Server returned: 301 Moved Permanently"*. No data arrives at my test page. From this, I assume the API isn't able to pursue the header's new location.

To make things worse, I don't know why the API is getting a 301 at all. I've used many tracing tools and none receives anything other than plain 200. I was first using a shared certificate, which forced me to use a different domain, and the test was indicated a 302 redirect (moved temporarily). I've installed a proper certificate for the domain, and the only change was to 301. Again, none of the URLs were being redirected at all.

What kind of hint can anyone give me about how (and why) the Push API thinks it needs to be redirected? I've honestly exausted all kinds of debugging I could think of, and nothing sends me any header pointing to redirection.

Comment: Can you specify the URL that foursquare is trying to call? I.e. the Push URL in your consumer details (https://foursquare.com/oauth)?